# Updating td ID when a new row is added

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function that inserts a new row in my table. Is there a way to update each new td ID with it's correct row and column from the table? For example, I have 5 rows to begin with and then I add a row. Row 5 column 1 id is "h-it-5-1" I need the next row to be "h-it-6-1" when it is added and then "h-it-7-1" and so on.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.addRow').click(function(){
            var markup = ("<tr>\
                                <td id='h-it-5-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                                <td id='h-it-5-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                                <td id='h-it-5-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                                <td id='h-it-5-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                                <td id='h-it-5-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                                <td class='h-text'>Enter Initiative 1</td>\
                                <td id='h-gi-2-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                                <td id='h-gi-2-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                                <td id='h-gi-2-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                                <td id='h-gi-2-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                                <td id='h-gi-2-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            </tr>");
            $(markup).insertBefore($(".bottom-row"));
            $('tr:last').css("width", "75px");
            $('tr:last').prev().css("text-align", "center");
        }); 
});
```

Comment: Firstly, `id` attributes need to be unique. Even applying the logic you're asking for this won't be the case as you're repeating some. Secondly, don't use incremental `id` attributes as they are an anti pattern. Use common classes and DOM traversal to find related elements.

Comment: Seems like it would be far easier and clearer to generate the cells via a loop and assign the ID there as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 5;
$('.addRow').click(function(){
        var markup = ("<tr>\
                            <td id='h-it-"+i+"-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-it-"+i+"-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-it-"+i+"-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-it-"+i+"-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-it-"+i+"-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td class='h-text'>Enter Initiative 1</td>\
                            <td id='h-gi-2-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-gi-2-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-gi-2-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-gi-2-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-gi-2-1' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                        </tr>");
        $(markup).insertBefore($(".bottom-row"));
        $('tr:last').css("width", "75px");
        $('tr:last').prev().css("text-align", "center");
        i++;
    }); 
});
```